# Postfix/Dovecot on Debian - Cannot connect account to Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, debian, smtp, postfix, dovecot

I recently installed/configured Postfix and Dovecot on my Debian Squeeze server. I can send mail using telnet so I know everything is working alright, but I cannot connect the account to Outlook. Is there something I'm missing? Related maybe to SASL or SMTP?

Comment: Any error messages maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming th'art requiring authentication for SMTP, the most likely explanation is that the "login" mechanism is not enabled in dovecot's config - the relevant file is probably `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` but may be something suitably named in `/etc/dovecot/conf.d`.  One of them should have a `mechanisms` line, which needs to include `login` - Outlook does not support the `plain` mechanism.

Comment: I have `mechanisms = plain login` in dovecot.conf and have switched it around to "plain, login" or "login plain" but to no avail unfortunately.

Comment: Sounds like I'm wrong, then.  Sorry I was unable to help.